# Phonegap 3.0+ How to print a document and/or send it to another device via email/airdrop/etc without using Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a Phonegap 3.1 iOS app.

---

**What I have currently:**
I'm using the [InAppBrowser plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) to view user-uploaded documents from a server.
The document types users upload are commonly (but not limited to) the following:

- .pdf
- .png, .gif, .jpeg
- .xls, .doc, .ppt
- .txt

---

**What I want to do:**
Viewing the files works well in the InAppBrowser, but now I am exploring ways that users could send the documents to each other.
Mobile Safari has a share button that allows a user to send a file by airdrop, message, mail, tweet, facebook or airprint.  I cannot, however, use Safari since it is a non-negotiable requirement that I do not expose the URL where these files are hosted.
The InAppBrowser allows me to hide the location from the user, which is not possible with Mobile Safari.  I want to be able to email and print a document without ever exposing the url where that document lives.
Is it possible to create the same sharing mechanism from within a Phonegap app?

---

**What I know so far**
I'm aware of the [Phonegap File plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) for uploading and downloading files.
If I were to download a file from the server so it was stored locally, how would I go about making it shareable (through email, airdrop, etc)?

From what I can tell, there are no relevant Phonegap 3.0+ compliant plugins to achieve this so I would think I need to create my own.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? we would also like a way to include airdrop in our phonegap app.

Comment: @Crashalot unfortunately, no.